# Text is appending multiple times due to incorrect Ajax data parameter. What is the correct parameter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to Ajax. I am getting the correct values from the PHP url in my Ajax function. The problem is that my data parameter is causing it to duplicate values.

Here is what is displaying on the actual webpage:

[image: error]

Here is the console.log output:

```
[2000, 335.1032163829112]
[2000, 335.1032163829112]
[2000, 335.1032163829112]
[2000, 335.1032163829112]
[2000, 335.1032163829112]
```

The form has 5 input fields, so I'm assuming since the Ajax function says `$('form').serialize()`, it's returning the requested values as many times are there are input fields.

What is the correct data parameter to send what I need? I only need 2 values that are calculated in my php script.

Here is the initial form, then the hidden div and Ajax call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Volume Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container page-heading">
    <h2>Volume Calculator</h2>
</div>
<!--<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="result.php">-->
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-container">
        <p class="calculate-heading">Calculate Volume of a Rectangle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container form-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="width" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Width: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control pull-left" id="width" name="width" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="length" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Length: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control pull-left" id="length" name="length" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="height" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Height: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control pull-left" id="height" name="height" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bs-linebreak">
            <!-- NOTHING. JUST A LINE BREAK -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
        <p class="calculate-heading">Calculate Volume of a Cone</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container form-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="radius" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Radius: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control pull-left" id="radius" name="radius" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="cone_height" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Height: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control pull-left" id="cone_height" name="cone_height"
                               required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container form-container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--<button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>-->
            <button type="button" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Hidden div that appears and Ajax function:**

```
<!-- NEW DIV THAT APPEARS ON FORM SUBMIT. HIDDEN BY DEFAULT VIA JQUERY -->
<div id="result-form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-container">
        <p class="calculate-heading">Summary of Calculations</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bs-linebreak">
            <!-- NOTHING. JUST A LINE BREAK -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
        <p class="calculate-heading calculate-heading-bold">Volume of Rectangle</p>
        <p id="length-p" class="calculate-heading">Length: </p>
        <p id="width-p" class="calculate-heading">Width: </p>
        <p id="height-p" class="calculate-heading">Height: </p>
        <br>
        <p id=rec_volume-p" class="calculate-heading">The Volume of the Rectangle is <strong></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
        <p class="calculate-heading calculate-heading-bold">Volume of a Cone</p>
        <p id="radius-p" class="calculate-heading">Radius: </p>
        <p id="cone_height-p" class="calculate-heading">Height: </p>
        <br>
        <p id="cone_volume-p" class="calculate-heading">The Volume of the Cone is <strong></strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    //HIDE THE DIV WHEN DOCUMENT IS LOADED
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#result-form').hide();
    });
    //GET RID OF DEFAULT HTML INVALID WARNING
    $('input').on("invalid", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //HANDLE BUTTON SUBMIT
    //LOOP THROUGH ALL INPUT ELEMENTS AND CHECK FOR INVALID FIELDS
    $('#submit-btn').click(function () {
        $('form input[type!=submit]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                alert("All fields are required");
                return false;
            }
            else {

                //AJAX CALL HERE
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'calculate.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(), //<-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM, BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO
                    success: function(output) {
                        var result = $.parseJSON(output);
                        console.log(result);
                        $('#result-form').show();
                        $('#length-p').append($('#length').val());
                        //REST OF THE VALUES UNDER THIS
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**The calculate.php script:**

```
<?php
//Rectangle dims
$width = $_POST['width'];
$length = $_POST['length'];
$height = $_POST['height'];

//Cone dims
$radius = $_POST['radius'];
$cone_height = $_POST['cone_height'];

//Rectangle volume
$rec_volume = $width * $length * $height;
//Cone volume
$cone_volume = 1/3 * (M_PI * pow($radius, 2) * $cone_height);

echo json_encode(array($rec_volume, $cone_volume));
```

I would really like to do this asynchronously instead of going to a completely new page. It just seems redundant. What is the correct data parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the name of your html inputs are all length or they do not have the name='' attribute at all.  Post the form html please.

Comment: @serverSentinel - added form

Comment: I see the problem, you're looping over the variables unnecessarily.

Comment: You're right! I had my ajax function inside my .each() function! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code loops over every variable in the form and issues an ajax call.  Each ajax call returns and appends the results to the #length-p element.

The solution is to only call the ajax once, after you've verified all the elements are filled out.  This should do it.

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function () {
    // validate, failures issue alert and exist the call.
    $('form input[type!=submit]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert("All fields are required");
            return false;
        }
     });

     // no failure, so issue the request. 
     //AJAX CALL HERE
     $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'calculate.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(), //<-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM, BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO
        success: function(output) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(output);
            console.log(result);
            $('#result-form').show();
            $('#length-p').append($('#length').val());
            //REST OF THE VALUES UNDER THIS
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly! I went and put my ajax function outside my .each() function and it worked. Coudn't believe I overlooked that. Duh!